# Odd normal on collision between a collider2D circle shape and a collider 2D box shape

Tags: game-physics, physics, godot

I'm building a little arkanoid clone with godot to learn how physics work but I have found a little problem when checking the collision between the ball and the paddle.

I have a paddle (character controller) with a box collider shape applied to it and a ball bouncing with a circle collider applied to it.

The problem is that when using move_and_collide and trying to get the collison normal in the ball script sometimes I get things like -> (0.543603, -0.839342) for the collision normal.

The paddle collision box is an AABB box. It is not transformed. Could it be that sometimes the collision happens on a box collider vertex and what I'm getting is the vertex normal instead of a normal face? I expected just to receive (1,0) or (0,1) or (-1,0) or (0,-1) as the normal.